# Trouble Converting a Hex String (in Lua)

Tags: string, function, lua, hex, readable

I've been trying different ways to read this hex string, and I cannot figure out how. Each method only converts part of it. The online converters don't do it, and this is the method I tried:

```
function string.fromhex(str)
  return (str:gsub('..', function (cc)
    return string.char(tonumber(cc, 16))
  end))
end

packedStr = "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"

local f = assert(io.open("unsquished.lua", "w+"));
f:write(packedStr:fromhex());
f:close()
```

This simply gives me a bunch of gibberish surrounded by a few readable strings.

Could someone please tell me how to convert the entirety of this string into readable format? Thank you!

Comment: This is hex-encoded Lua bytecode file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break your `packedStr` in parts of 2

1. **1b** = 27
2. **4c** = 76
3. **75** = 117
4. **61** = 97

and so forth. When you use `string.char()` with the resulting decimal output, it converts them to equivalent ASCII values. Of the total possible 256 ASCII values in extended ASCII table, only [95 are printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii_table#ASCII_printable_characters).

Thus, you'll always receive the gibberish text. Here's what you'd receive when trying to print each of the character separately: http://codepad.org/orM7pmAb and that is the only possible "readable" output.

Comment: Furthermore, that output looks like compiled lua byte code... Try running it?